# How to list properties of a chart object in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to clone(using VBA) some charts and be able to change them for that I need to know what they contain.

How to list properties of a chart object in VBA, more like an object dump in other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VBE, use the Locals window:

[image: Screenshot of partial view of Locals window for Chart]

You can then copy any existing charts, and simply manipulate the properties that need to be changed for each, or you can create new charts on-the-fly, setting the properties as needed.