# Stepping through macro code that is copy-pasted and executed using Run Application

Tags: debugging, excel, excel-2010, vba

This is my first time on this amazing forum. I am also very new to vba (3 weeks).

1. I have 2 macros: CallerMac, WorkerMac. These are in separate modules within the "Modules" node of my VBAProject.
2. In its code, CallerMac imports a .bas file (which has the WorkerMac code) and executes it through a " Application.Run"
3. When the user is handed this code, they will run "CallerMac" (whose code wont change much) while the code imports the "WorkerMac" (likely to change often)
4. How can I, for debugging purposes, "F8"/Step into the copied code (WorkerMac) during execution?

   Please let me know how I can rephrase my question if it doesn't say much to you or if I should have searched for it differently (I did a lot of searching before posting this code)

Many thanks.

Comment: +1 this is the sort of question that every noob should ask :)  being self-taught, I literally didn't know about this until after several months of programming.  You should also learn how to use the `Immediate` window and the `Locals` window.  In the Immediate pane, you can query and execute most statements, and the Locals pane displays all of the variables currently in scope of the active procedure/function, and you can browse their values & properties.  Super helpful to debug, but also to familiarize with the object model.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066878/how-to-list-properties-of-a-chart-object-in-vba/16066997#16066997) is an example of using the Locals pane to examine the properties of a `chartObject.Chart`.

Comment: Thanks David Zemens. I did figure out how to use the Immediate & Locals. And you confirmed that I was using it the right way. I haven't figured out how to use the "Watch" feature though. I haven't delved deeply into the documentation much however.

Comment: FWIW: I don't do much with Watch, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a breakpoint at the beginning of "WorkerMac" as you step through "CallerMac", and then use F8 to continue running "WorkerMac" in step mode.

You can add breakpoints by right clicking on a line that is an executable statement and going to Toggle->Breakpoint, or by clicking on the bar on the left next to the code. It should show a red circle in the bar and highlight the line in red.

Comment: +1 Also you can add/toggle breakpoints by putting your cursor on a line in the VBE and pressing `F9`

Comment: Ah, forgot about that one. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ratafia for the quick response. That worked well. Thanks David Zemens for the additional pointer.

Comment: I highly recommend you use David's tip on the Immediate and Locals panes as they are invaluable for checking your output before it hits a sheet. Especially useful for arrays and loops.

Comment: Thanks Ratafia. Will do