# Find out all properties of a particular bar chart for further replication

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose long ago I have created a **bar chart** and modified it as I wanted (colors, size, etc.). Is there a way to see all properties of this chart in VBA so later I can create exactly the same chart?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066878/how-to-list-properties-of-a-chart-object-in-vba) can help?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/176817/excel-graphs-how-do-i-apply-a-graph-template-format  and http://excelribbon.tips.net/T008447_Understanding_Custom_Chart_Templates.html

Comment: the way @AlexP linked is the only real way to do... depending on the chart and its propertys, some propertys don't exist.... if you would go for every possible bit, there would be billions of propertys (while most just pop errors cus they do not exist in your chart, but could be there if it where different)... the only right way, is to know what exists and what does not from the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

Load it into a chartobject and then access the properties through the chart.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim cht As ChartObject

Dim c As ChartObject
Set c = ws.ChartObjects(1)
MsgBox (c.Chart.ChartTitle.Text)
MsgBox (c.Chart.Legend.Position)
MsgBox (c.Chart.ChartArea.Width)
```