# VBA How to get values from selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need put data from selected cells to array. How to do it? I cant find any example. I know how to get value from one cell by `ActiveCell.Value` but how its work with multiple selection. Guess I should selected range put to variable as object and process it by foreach loop. Can anyone write example for it?

Solution:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

For Each OneCell In Selection
 MsgBox (OneCell.Value)
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `A = R.Value` where `A` is a variant and `R` is the target range is all you need (assuming that `R` is a rectangular range).

Comment: I dont know target range, its depend what was selected by user.

Comment: `Selection` is the range that the user has selected (unless you are getting input from the user in some other way). You need to show your code and explain your  problem -- as it is your question is very unclear.

Comment: Would Selection.Value work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `OneCell.Value` as the cell itself holds the value.
If you want to get the cells formula then use `OneCell.FormulaR1C1`.

```
    For Each OneCell In Selection
        MsgBox (OneCell)
    Next OneCell
```

Answer (score 2):

`Application.Selection` is not always `Range` (for example if Shape(s) or ActiveX Control(s) are selected), and `Selection.Value` returns different things depending on what is selected:

- cell value if only one cell is selected
- 2D Variant array of cell values if more than one cell is selected
- error if the object(s) selected don't have a `.Value` property

If more than one area is selected, `.Value` returns the value(s) only of the first area.

---

```
If TypeOf Selection Is Excel.Range Then
    Debug.Print Selection.Address(0, 0)

    For Each area In Selection.Areas
        Debug.Print area.Address(0, 0)
    Next
Else
    Debug.Print TypeName(Selection)
End If
```

The [Locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066878/how-to-list-properties-of-a-chart-object-in-vba) window can make it easier to see the contents of the `Application.Selection`

Comment: if a single row of cells is selected, `Selection.Value` still returns a 2D array,  size (1 to 1, 1 to n)

Comment: is there a reason why the first `Debug.Print Selection.Address(0, 0)` is there? in my view the second one (`Debug.Print area.Address(0, 0)`) will catch all "selections/areas".

Comment: @Albin the first one shows the address of the whole selection, and second one shows how to loop the rectangular areas, as non-contiguous range can't be put in array directly

Comment: but still, essentially the both show the same data, right? Only that `selection.` shows the selected ranges "all at once" and `area.` shows each range "individually".

Comment: @Albin yes, exactly